# IPSEC VPN between Mikrotik & Fortigate30D Device

Tags: networking, router, vpn

I want to setup an IPSEC VPN tunnel between a mikrotik 912UAG device and a fortigate30D device so that anything connected on my mikrotik LAN is able to communicate to anything connected on my fortigate LAN.
My mikrotik device has an ip address of 172.16.99.1(LAN) and my fortigate has an ip address of 10.0.0.1(LAN)

A dialup connection is being used between the two devices where the mikrotik is utilising a 3g connection and the fortigate is connected to a local ADSL line through a modem.

The modem(192.168.1.1) is connected to the WAN interface of the fortigate30D device and assigning it an ip address of 192.168.1.10.

I have setup the mikrotik device to use the external IP address of my modem and have also setup port forwarding on my modem to forward UDP 500/UDP 4500 to my fortigate30D device. However, it appears that none of the VPN packets are getting to my fortigate30D device.

Can anyone provide any insight/help please?

Answer (score 1):

Some 3g providers block vpn protocols like l2tp, I had plenty of luck dialing a pptp vpn from behind 3g networks. Test the mikrotik on a separate dsl line and see if you can dial over dsl.